# NameError: name 'ListaFinal' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo esta función:

```
Lista = ["SD;TC;10", "NA;TD;15"]

def Seleccion(Lista):
    
    ListaFinal = []
    
    for Registro in Lista:
        Persona, Canal, Valor = Registro.split(";",2)
        if Canal == "TC":
            ClaveValor = (Persona,Valor)
            ListaFinal.append(ClaveValor)
        return ListaFinal
```

Cuando la ejecuto me da

```
NameError: name 'ListaFinal' is not defined
```

La verdad no tengo claro el error, entiendo que la variable `ListaFinal` la estoy declarando antes de recorrer la Lista de entrada.

Comment: Probe tu código y me retornó `[('SD', '10')]` ... ¿correcto?

Comment: Hola, si, eso debería ser el resultado. ¿Será algún error de la versión de python que tengo instalada ?

Comment: si ese es todo tu código y que haces `print(Seleccion(Lista ))` no debería de dar error. La versión de python no tiene nada que ver

Comment: Tienen toda la razón a la hora de verificar el resultado no estaba llamando a la función, sino a la lista resultado. Muchas gracias.